# how to recover/continue from cancelled 20.04 to 22.04?

Tags: do-release-upgrade

I thought I was telling it to "cancel" (not send) the error about this service I don't use anyway.
It canceled the whole installation.
I did not reboot yet .. what is the best way to proceed?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking, but before starting from scratch did you try to `apt install --fix-broken`?

Answer (score 1):

I just dared to reboot.. then apt upgrade fixed the rest.